# Update statement with join and two where conditions

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I need the update to do:

- update my summary table TIME column with the user-edited TIME value
- compare the new TIME, using ID's from my summary table and hour_interval table to join tables
- find the correct row ID where the new TIME falls within (there are two columns with start and end hours; example would be: start column - 04:00:00  end column 06:00:00)
- update the summary table with the correct interval row ID using the summary table ID

The code executes, but doesn't update the interval ID.  Suggestions?

```
UPDATE summary S  
JOIN hour_interval H  
ON S.hourinterval_id = H.hourinterval_id 
SET S.hourinterval_id = H.hourinterval_id 
WHERE ('$new_time' BETWEEN H.start_hour AND H.end_hour) 
AND summary_id = '$summary_id'"
```

```
hourinterval_id start_hour  end_hour
1               4:00:00 5:59:59
2               6:00:00 7:59:59
3               8:00:00 9:59:59
4              10:00:00 11:59:59
5              12:00:00 13:59:59
6              14:00:00 15:59:59
7              16:00:00 17:59:59
8              18:00:00 19:59:59
```

Comment: Do you have a specific $new_time you're working with?  Also, it would be helpful to see contents of the hour_interval table.

Comment: Added the hour_interval table columns.  An example, of $new_time value would be '09:33:00'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE summary S  
JOIN hour_interval H  
ON '$new_time' BETWEEN H.start_hour AND H.end_hour
SET S.hourinterval_id = H.hourinterval_id 
WHERE summary_id = '$summary_id'"
```